# Is it possible to add a hyper-link to a GitHub Pages?

Tags: html, web, github, hyperlink, markdown

I have a site on GitHub pages and want to add a hyperlink to an external site. When I do `<a href =""`I it doesn't work and says that the site isn't hosted on GitHub Pages (404 error).

How can I fix this ?

Comment: The same thing going on over here If you found any solution please tell me.

Comment: @NANO, OP: Can you give an example hyperlink?

Comment: @SwetankPoddar Hyperlink for what like my project's GitHub folder/repository sorry but it is private It is a big e-learning project so I can't give you Its link.

Comment: You have to give some example link that doesn't work for you, even if it's not the real link that you'll end up using. Most likely you forgot the `http://` prefix or something.

Comment: @NANO: No, what I mean is, what does your hyperlink look like? is it like: `<a href="www.something.com"> Something </a>`

Comment: @SwetankPoddar Yes it is like that you know traditional HTML code.

Comment: @NANO: You need to add `http://` if you want to link to some other website, otherwise github pages considers it a relative url and will lead to `www.yourpage.github.io/www.something.com`

Comment: @NANO: Great, I added it as an answer :)

Comment: OP, please read [ask] and remember to include code when you ask questions in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you are linking to an external page, you need to add `http://` or `https://` otherwise it will be considered a relative URL (w.r.t your Github page URL)

So,

Rather than using

```html
<a href="www.something.com"> Something </a>
```

You should use

```html
<a href="http://www.something.com"> Something </a>
<!-- or -->
<a href="https://www.something.com"> Something </a>
```